# How do I open UIDatePicker when tapping on UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uidatepicker

I have view controller that contains three UITextFields called "Name", "Location" and "Birthday".

I have this code here which opens a UIDatePicker:

```
// Open date picker
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    // Make a new view, or do what you want here
    UIDatePicker *pv = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,245,0,0)];
    [self.view addSubview:pv];
    return NO;
}
```

Here I have two problems.

**Problem 1**

When I tap any field the datepicker opens. I just want to open the datepicker when "Birthday" is tapped.

**Problem 2**

When I tap on a field, then tap again, it opens another datepicker.

How can I stop this from happening?

Peter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead try this on viewDidLoad:

```
UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
birtdayTextField.inputView = datePicker; //birtdayTextField is your "birthday text field"
```

Comment: It worked like a charm :) can the same method be applied to a UIPickerView?

Answer (score 1):

For opening the datepicker only for a specific textField, check the `(UITextField *)textField` before opening datePicker. You can set tags to each textField and then use that tag to differentiate.

For your second issue, you need to use `resignFirstResponder`